# React JS. Type Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I did face the following problem. In section where **{this.props.items.map((item, index) =>** I got a type of error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined On Reacts and I don`t know what is happened? I am a novice in programming and follow the tutorial in React JS.

** My Code: App.js**

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        class Header extends Component {
          render() {
            console.log('items', this.props.items);
            return (
              <div>
                {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
                  <a href={item.link} key={index}>{item.label}</a>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
        export default Header;
```

**My Code Header.js**

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
const menu = [
  {
    link: '/articles',
    label: 'Articles'
  },
  {
    link: '/contacts',
    label: 'Contacts'
  },
  {
    link: '/posts',
    label: 'Posts'
  }
];
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Header items={menu}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Show the `items` object and how do you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a constructor in your React component. This will inform the React supertype what the value of your props are. React will then make these props available as instance variables for use in your **render()** method via **this.props.items**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    console.log('items', this.props.i...
     ...

}
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.items` is empty. For avoid the error you can use if...else statement.

```
        {this.props.items ? this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
          <a href={item.link} key={index}>{item.label}</a>
        ) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that items come from an API endpoint, that means that this.props.items will be undefined when the render() function will be called for the first time.

To have this working you have to:

1. Verify if this.props.items !== undefined and then to map it
2. Use default props

`Header.prototype.defaultProps = {items: []};`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('items', this.props.items);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items && this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
          <a href={item.link} key={index}>{item.label}</a>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Header.prototype.defaultProps = {
  items: []
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle

Comment: I guess you wanted to comment on a different answer.

Comment: But yours does not work. I not sure what the problem, where?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the defaultProps into Header.prototype. I just updated the answer with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Why in your App.js file use the name Header? it's a bit confusing...

The error is produced because the prop items is empty... why??? dunno yet.

I create an example in jsfiddle with your code... changing the names :)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header items={menu}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ru5fd59n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you do not import the first bit of code in the second, I'd say you're using the first piece of code as your entry point since you're getting the error and not ever touching the second piece. Since you never get to the code where you define and pass menu, this.props.items is undefined.

You need to flip the names of the components, the Header.js and the App.js. You should then

```
import Header from './Header'
```

And you should rename the second piece of code to App and export it as such for clarity sake. It should look like this.

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('items', this.props.items);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
          <a href={item.link} key={index}>{item.label}</a>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header'

const menu = [
  {
    link: '/articles',
    label: 'Articles'
  },
  {
    link: '/contacts',
    label: 'Contacts'
  },
  {
    link: '/posts',
    label: 'Posts'
  }
];
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Header items={menu}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

If you're executing app directly though, there is no need to export it.